# Laravel: unable to retrieve one to many camelCase method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to retrieve the inverse side of the one to many relationship where the method is **camelCase**. i.e

**Owning Class: OneToMany**

```
class Brand extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**Owned Class**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function MyBrand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

**retrieve the inverse related model like this:**

```
$product = Product::find(1);
$brand = $product->my_brand;
dd($brand->name);
```

> Error, Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

I also tried this:

```
$brand = $product->myBrand;
```

it did not work.

however, if i make my method like below it works:

```
public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}
```

**question is** : how to make it work when the method is in CameCase ?

Comment: never tried it but probably it would be something like `$product->_my_brand`. If you rename the method to `myBrand` then it would be called `$product->my_brand`

Comment: You can acces the name like this: dd($product->brand->name). You can also do this: dd($product->brand);

Comment: hi @MihaiMatei . i tried it. it did not work

Comment: hi @Collin. you miss read the question.  this $product->brand->name only works if the method is called brand. i am talking about having a camCase method name i.e public function MyBrand()

Comment: when you `dd($brand)` what it returns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Specify it's foreign key in relationship**

```
class Product extends Model
{
   public function MyBrand()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class,'brand_id');
      //brand_id is foreign key in your product table
   }
}

$product = Product::find(1)->with('MyBrand'); //But it will be good to eager load it
$product->MyBrand->name; //It will definitely return name now
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 public function my_brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}
```

And call this relation as,

```
$product = Product::find(1);
$brand = $product->my_brand;
dd($brand->name);
```

Comment: It does not work. this is the message: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: What value hold $brand veriable? check it dd($brand);

Comment: i am not clear what u are asking? could you please be a little clearer

Comment: First you  check that the value of $brand variable by using dd($brand);
$product = Product::find(1);
$brand = $product->my_brand;
dd($brand);
I think it will return null. Due to this you are getting this error

Answer (score 1):

You need to change, method name in brand(), because Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column in the Brands table.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

If you want to keep it MyBrand() you need to specify foreign key:

```
public function MyBrand()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class,'product_id');
   }
```